# shell script that takes a file name as an argument and deletes this file from every directory above the pwd in Unix / Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: shell, unix

my shell script is as follows.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "pass the file name"
    exit
 fi
fl=$1
ch=1
h=/home

while [ $ch -eq 1 ]
do
    cd ..
    p=`pwd`
    echo "$p/$fl"
    rm `echo "$p/$fl"` 2> /dev/nullif [ $p = $h ]
    then
            ch=0
    fi
done
```

but when executing shows a syntax error.
 line16: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
 line 16:`        then'

What is the mistake in this script?

Comment: you are missing if

Comment: i corrected the syntax error.but the script didn't work correctly.It looks like an infinite loop when a file name is given.Is there any error in this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misplaced if the script.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "pass the file name"
    exit
fi

fl=$1
ch=1
h=/home

while [ $ch -eq 1 ]
do
    cd ..
    p=`pwd`
    echo "$p/$fl"
    rm `echo "$p/$fl"` 2> /dev/null
    if [ $p = $h ]
    then
            ch=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: i corrected the syntax error.but the script didn't work correctly.It looks like an infinite loop when a file name is given.Is there any error in this script.